# Can I Achieve this Layout in Xaml?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have an array of objects that is basically a grid of Ids/Values for various Categories.  If I bind the collection ordered by category can I bind a "grid" of textboxes in a ListView? The ID values will be known. Example to clarify below. I can handle the UI, but I can't figure out how to "place" by the ID but show/bind the value unless I punt and create the UI in the code-behind.

```
public class MyItem {        
   string ID;
   string Value;
   string Category;
}

with values: 
  { id1,  value1a, catA}
  { id2, value1b, catA}
  { id1,  value2a, catB}
  { id2, value2a, catB}
```

Desired UI binding (ListView with each row showing values of each category):

```
value1a       value1b
value2a       value2b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would suggest you use `GridView` instead of the `ListView`

```
<GridView x:Name="categoryGrid" SizeChanged="GridView_SizeChanged" >
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
       </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Use the SizeChanged event handler to set the width of the GridViewItem.

```
private async void GridView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ItemsWrapGrid itemsWPGrid = (ItemsWrapGrid)((GridView)sender).ItemsPanelRoot;
        double viewWidth = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Width;
        itemsWPGrid.ItemWidth = (viewWidth) / 2;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

And don't forget to set the `categoryGrid.ItemsSource = yourCustomList;`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ListView` and bind some properties to your Model. For example

```
   <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding ID}" />
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" />
                <Etc />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: You can create a StackPanel inside the row with Orientation="Horizontal" and place some TextBlocks inside with Bindings.